# Android WebView remote url with local font file in assets?

Tags: android

I am trying to reference a local font file in the assets folder as follows:-

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('file:///android_asset/MyFont.ttf');  
}
```

And then using

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.dummy.com/page_that_uses_font_css.html");
```

But it seems that this does not work, I have searched stack and the web and found that most examples of doing something similar to this can only do so with loadDataWithBaseURL(...);

I have also tried to override `WebResourceResponse WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest(...)` but it seems that @font-face src references are not picked up by this method and therefore unable to return my font as an asset stream.

Is it even possible to do this at all, any other way?

If anyone could recommend an alternative or provide help on this issue it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can change the html code too. How does your HTML look like?